# How to calculate interest rate in compound interest

Tags: finance

I'm trying to calculate the *interest rate* in **compound interest**, but I find that the online formula can't get the answer I want. I don't know why. Does anyone know what the specific formula is? I know the calculator can done that, but I need to use formula for programming.

The formula I use is **r = ( FV / PV )1/n - 1**, but the result is 7.56 something, but not as what the picture shows.

[please look at this question as a example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUGrw.png)

Comment: Every month and I have already know PV, FV, how many year it takes.. it is all in the picutures.

Comment: Getting the rate involves logarithms.

Comment: [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=solve+%281%2Br%2F12%29%5E30*5000%3D6000) is the basic expression.  You can solve for $r$ by taking logs of both sides, ending up with $\frac r{12}=e^{\ln\big(\frac {6000}{5000}\big)/30}-1$

Comment: I don't know how to calculte radix/base number

Comment: The base is whatever you want.  In my comment, I used $e$ as in the natural log, but you could use $10$ or anything else you like so long as you are consistent.

Comment: Note:  always good to do the continuously compounded computation as a quick approximation.  Here we'd get $e^{2.5r}=\frac 65\implies r\approx .0729$ which should be (and is) quite close to the actual answer.

Comment: very appreciate, I use your way to solve the question and it is right,  now I  understand how you solve this problem, very smart , thankyou very much.

Comment: Basically the formula for the future value is

$$C_n=C_0\cdot \left(1+\frac{i}{m} \right)^n$$

$m=12$ is the number of compoundings per year. $i$ is the nominal interest year. $C_0$ is the initial deposit. And $C_n$ is the deposit after $n$ months.

Thus your equation is $6000=5000\cdot \left(1+\frac{i}{12} \right)^{30}$. Solving for i.

$$i=12\cdot \left(\left(\frac{6}{5}\right)^{\frac1{30}}-1\right)=0.07315068...=7.32\%$$

(rounded to two decimal places)

Answer (score 1):

We have the following formula for calculating the future value ($FV$) of a deposit ($PV$) with an annual interest rate of $r\%$ compounded $m$ times per year for a total of $n$ times:
$$FV = PV\left(1 + \frac{r}{m}\right)^n.$$
In the example you linked we are given the following information: $PV = 5000$, $FV = 6000$, $m = 12$ and $n = 2.5 \times 12 = 30$. All that we need to find is $r$, the annual interest rate.

Plugging the known values into the formula:
$$6000 = 5000 \left( 1 + \frac{r}{12} \right)^{30}.$$
We need to solve for $r$ by rearranging this equation:
\begin{align}
r &= 12 \left( \sqrt[30]{\frac{6000}{5000}} - 1 \right) \\ 
&= 0.07315\ldots.
\end{align}
So the annual interest rate is approximately $7.32\%$.

The general formula for annual interest $r$ (which you can get by rearranging the original compound interest formula) is
$$r = m \left( \sqrt[n]{\frac{FV}{PV}} - 1\right).$$
Note that taking the $n$-th root of $FV/PV$ is the same as raising $FV/PV$ to the power of $1/n$.